# Determine the value of a

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Please,this is the last problem that i need to solve:

Can you help me?I don't know how to start.

Determine the value of **a** such that the vectors **A** = (a, 4), **B** = (2,5) are parallel.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\bf A$ being parallel to $\bf B$?

Comment: Hint: 2 vectors are parallel iff one is a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: i dont know any thing about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two vectors $A$ and $B$ are parallel, when the following equality holds
$$A=kB$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$
Thus we have a system of equations
$$ka=2$$
$$4k=5$$
$$\implies$$
$$k=\frac{5}{4}$$
Substituting this in the first equation we get
$$\frac{5}{4}a=2$$
$$\implies$$
$$a=\frac{8}{5}$$

Thus
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{8}{5} \\
  4
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Is that the answer?

Comment: one more question,please.So where do i need to start to copy??From 5/4a = 2?

Comment: The answer starts at the beginning, at A=kB. Will you accept the answer, I think it resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If $v $ is parallel to $u $, then there exists a number $\lambda$ to which we call a scalar such that $v = \lambda u $.

Because a vector is only equal to another if all components are equal, one by one, we are able to write a system of equations.

You can say your vectors are parallel when there is a $\lambda$ such that $(a, 4) = \lambda (2, 5) $. Equaling component by component we get

$
\begin {cases}
a = 2\lambda\\
4 = 5\lambda
\end {cases}$

Comment: that's the answer?

Comment: @luis the answer is the value of $a $ after solving that system.

Comment: @luis My answer has the completed computation, if you wish to check your solutions.

Comment: @RSerrao then a = 2a?

Comment: @luis by a poor choosing of the letters they seemed the same, sorry. Refer to my question again, i substituted one symbol by a new one to avoid confusion. The answer is solving the linear system